# Help with unmounting a drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I'm recovering lost data off a hard drive using `ddrescue` and 
[How to Recover Data Even When Hard Drive is Damaged](http://www.geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-recover-data-even-when-hard-drive-is-damaged/)
I've got all the data transferred to my destination drive and so now its time to restore the new raw image.

My problem is when I go to unmount the drive it says the device is busy.  What am I missing?  Please help.

Comment: `Device is busy` can mean two things: either a process is actually using a file on the drive, or some user is viewing the drive, either through the file manager or in the command prompt. Did you `cd` out of the drive before the `umount` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through that guide, `/dev/sda` is mounted at `mnt`, and you are still in directory `mnt/recovery` at the point you try to unmount it.

You can't umount it because you are still using it, so change directory first:-

```
cd ~
```

and then

```
sudo umount /dev/sda
```

and it should unmount. If not, edit your question to include what happened.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank u so much!!! U guys are awesome!!!!!

Comment: i will upvote for you brother as the questioner is satisfied!

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
sudo umount -l /mountpoint/of/your/partition
```

`-l` forces the partition to unmount even if it is in use / busy.